# Panda Data Frame indexing not ordering correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

I want to ask a question about panda's in python - specifically about it's `DataFrame()` function.

I have the following data that I want to covert to a data frame:

```
pop = {'Nevada': {2001: 2.4, 2002: 2.9}, 'Ohio': {2000: 1.5, 2001: 1.7, 2002: 3.6}}
frame3 = pd.DataFrame(pop)
```

I expected that the outer keys of the nested dictionary to be the column names and the inner keys to be the index names:

Note the interpreter syntax is iPython running on Jupyter Notebook Python 3

```
     Nevada   Ohio
2000    NaN    1.5
2001    2.4    1.7
2002    2.9    3.6
```

However, I continuously get the data with the keys arranged in the wrong order:

```
>> frame3
        Nevada   Ohio
2001    2.4    1.7
2002    2.9    3.6
2000    NaN    1.5
```

and I can't seem to make the indexes appear in the order that I desire.

Why is this happening? How can I rectify the matter?

The odd thing is, this is what appears in my Jupyter notebook:

[image: Jupyter Output]

but when using `learnpython.org`'s IDE, I get the following expected output:

[image: Expected output from learnpython.org]

Again, the same erroneous output is observed on my iPython:

[image: Erroneous error on iPython]

Comment: Can you an example of what exactly you want it to look like?

Comment: @Chris I edited the code thanks to vik1245

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put it in the data frame and sort it. Check this out :

```
pandas_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(pop).sort_index()
print(pandas_dataframe)

Out[128]:
    Nevada  Ohio
2000    NaN 1.5
2001    2.4 1.7
2002    2.9 3.6
```

Comment: I thought the Panda would sort the data automatically. I will accept your answer since it's the cleanest, but out of curiousity (unless I'm mistaken of course) why is this not observed here?

Comment: What exactly not observed here?

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution can be :

```
pop = {'Nevada': {2000:np.nan,2001: 2.4, 2002: 2.9}, 'Ohio': {2000: 1.5, 2001: 1.7, 2002: 3.6}}
frame3 = pd.DataFrame(pop)
```

Or to sort index after creating the dataframe:

```
frame3 = pd.DataFrame(pop).sort_index()
```

The result is what you want:

```
      Nevada  Ohio
2000     NaN   1.5
2001     2.4   1.7
2002     2.9   3.6
```

Comment: I've updated by question to further reflect the inconsistency in my output with respect to that which I receive in Jupyter, so it appears this is a Jupyter-based issue. Although, your answer is appreciated and upvoted!

Comment: Yes, probably the problem is the Jupyter notebook default. when there are no sorting preferences it puts the one with empty values at the end...

Comment: It appears so. I've just run the exact same file on three different Jupyter versions and iPythons and all have returned erroneous. Interesting.